# Open source Android helper library project I can contribute to?

Tags: android

Over the past years, my own library with many helper methods has grown a lot and I kind of lost the vision how to properly sort it.

I tried with simple folder structure like `UI/TextView`, `UI/EditText` and so on. My logic was to have the general name for root, then type name for folder, then classes inside. But in time, it so grew that I now cannot find many methods and I discovered that I have multiple duplicated methods.

Can anyone direct me to a good and quality Android helper project where I can see how they sorted their library?

Or is there any public open source project where Android developers contribute with their own helper methods aiming to creating the ultimate helper library? If such thing exist, I would rather fill the gaps with my own methods and use the whole project in my applications, then continue upgrading my own library.

Comment: Or... you could simply add a class (call it `Common`, for instance) to contain the shared methods.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein The problem is that in time it gets disorganized and I spend too much time updating and maintaining it. Ideally, it would be easier if there is 1k of us updating such library which other can use or contribute.

Comment: Because I'm sick (or nerd, if you prefer), I do so. I also specialize the common classes (one for graphics, one for data, one for utility methods, ...). And I'm so sick (or nerd) that I also sort the methods (and variables, constants, enums, ...) alphabetically!! Unfortunately, I don't know how others work, since I tend to use as little external libraries as possible, often reoptimizing them MY WAY.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein LOL. Then I am nerd as well. If not confidential, is there a way you upload a snapshots of your structure? You can blur parts you find confidential.

Comment: But then I would have to kill you. ;) Jokes apart, it's stuff which belongs to my company, I should blur out nearly everything.

Comment: You should know not to ask such questions.  Wait for it... Maybe android-query aquery.  I'm using it for authentication with google and some async web request stuff.  I got the authentication working faster than if I had rolled my own.

Comment: it's very small but it may help https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Try this [library](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap) it's very interesting .
It's the android-bootstrap library , while it's still in the beginning and needs improvements but the necessity of such libraries may make it a very important project , that you contribution to may be very helpful for you and for the community , the design of the library code is easy which makes it easy to understand and you can easily add futures as you want .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @henrywright Thank you for your feedback i really appreciate your advice,  will change it .